# Inner measure equals to outer measure if the set is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is an exercise from the book Measure,Integration & Real Analysis by Sheldon Axler.
For A ⊂ R, the quantity
sup {| F | : F is a closed bounded subset of R and F ⊂ A }
is called the inner measure of A.
here |F| is the outer measure of F.
Show that if A is a Lebesgue measurable subset of R, then the inner measure
of A equals the outer measure of A.

I could prove this if F given  in the definition above is just a closed subset of A.
Inner measure is less than or equal to outer measure by definition. If A is lebesgue measurable, then for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a closed subset F of such that |A| -$\epsilon$  < |F| .If F is bounded, the proof is done. But why is F bounded?

Answer (score 2):

$|A|-\epsilon <|F\cap [-N,N]|$ if $N$ is large enough. $F\cap [-N,N]$ is a  closed and bounded subset of $A$.

(Note: This argument works if $A$ has finite measure. When $m(A)=\infty$ you have to argue separately).